# How do I run grunt from a different folder than my root project

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

Is there a way to tell grunt which grunt.js file to use?

I have an `f:\a\b\tools` folder that contains `grunt.cmd, node.exe,...`,
my actual web app with `GruntFile.js` and all the local `node_modules` is in `f:\a\c\my_app`

Running grunt from `a\c\my_app` works fine but trying to run grunt from some other folder say a does not seem to work. I am new to grunt and may be I am missing something obvious.

```
f:\a>grunt --config c\GruntFile.js
```

> grunt-cli: The grunt command line interface. (v0.1.6)
>
> Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
>
> If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or grunt hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more information about installing and configuring grunt, please see the Getting Started guide:

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can set two parameters `--base` and `--gruntfile`

From `grunt --help`:

`--base` Specify an alternate base path. By default, all file paths are relative to the Gruntfile. (grunt.file.setBase) *

`--gruntfile` Specify an alternate Gruntfile. By default, grunt looks in the current or parent directories for the nearest Gruntfile.js or Gruntfile.coffee file.

So, you can execute:

```
grunt --base c\my_app --gruntfile c\my_app\GruntFile.js mytask
```

Comment: FWIW, using `--base` did not work for me but using `--gruntfile` did.

Comment: How can this be set as 'default'? We have a Generic Grunt file that can be used in all of our applications so we want it in a folder (submodule) but still just want to run everything by just calling grunt rather than having to type --gruntfile every time.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the watch file. initial run is OK, but when a watch triggers a run the path is doubles and errors out: `unable to find gruntfile "c\my_app\c\my_app\gruntfile.js"`

Comment: Just to update for grunt-cli versions >= 1.0.0, the command is now: `grunt --base=c\my_app --gruntfile=c\my_app\GruntFile.js mytask`

[source](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-cli/issues/101)

Answer (score 1):

Since grunt 1.3 you can omit `--gruntfile`.

So, instead of

`grunt --base c\my_app --gruntfile c\my_app\GruntFile.js mytask`

you can just

`grunt --base c\my_app mytask` (and `--base` can be replaced with `-b`)

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise you to run it from your app directory because the modules are installed into nodes_modules, etc. 
you must move to your app directory and run grunt:

```
cd f:
cd  a\c\my_app
grunt {yourTasks}
```

Comment: by specifying the `--base` parameter you can get rid of it. see @Renan's answer.