# Do I have to install grunt locally or is it just best practice ...?

Tags: bash, gruntjs

or neither.

I installed both grunt-cli and grunt globally as such

```
inst_grunt(){

  # installs the grung-cli to
  # /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
  sudo npm install -g grunt-cli

  # installs grunt based upon the package.json file to 
  # /usr/local/lib/node_modules/Grunt
  sudo npm install -g
 }
```

I thought I could simply run

```
 grunt --gruntfile /Users/a/root/config/Gruntfile.js watch
```

as stated here:

[How do I run grunt from a different folder than my root project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873356/how-do-i-run-grunt-from-a-different-folder-than-my-root-project)

but alas I get this error:

> as-MacBook-Air:config a$ grunt --gruntfile
>   /Users/a/root/config/Gruntfile.js grunt-cli: The grunt command line
>   interface. (v0.1.13)
>
> Fatal error: Unable to find local grunt.
>
> If you're seeing this message, either a Gruntfile wasn't found or
>   grunt hasn't been installed locally to your project. For more
>   information about installing and configuring grunt, please see the
>   Getting Started guide:
>
> http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

The grunt file is there so I'm assuming it is looking for a local grunt installation.

Answer (score 0):

You do have to install it locally in order to call functions on it within the gruntfile.

This way your project can specify what version of Grunt should be used (edit) in your package.json file.

Comment: So you are saying I have to install it locally? If so why is there a global install option ?

Comment: global installs allow you to use a package from the command line (i.e. running grunt tasks)  local installs allow you to use modules within your code (i.e. require('grunt'))  reference https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/